# How to execute 7 select prepared statement in one go in mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, model-view-controller

```
private void view(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

        String logined_email = (String) session.getAttribute("e-mail");
        data = dbconn.viewMyData(logined_email);
        request.setAttribute("mydata", data);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("myData.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);
}
public void dbconn() {

        try {
            String JDBC_Driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName(JDBC_Driver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/connectiondb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

public void viewMyData(String login_email_addr){

    dbconn();
    String sql1 = "SELECT * From art_culture WHERE email = ? ";
    String sql2 = "SELECT * From education WHERE email =  ? ";
    String sql3 = "SELECT * From fashion_beauty WHERE email = ? ";
    String sql4 = "SELECT * From food_travel WHERE email = ? "; 
    String sql5 = "SELECT * From health_fitness WHERE email = ? ";
    String sql6 = "SELECT * From literature WHERE email = ? ";
    String sql7 = "SELECT * From nature_wildlife WHERE email = ? ";

}
```

The **email** value in condition is same for all queries.
**view** method is in **servlet** that is behaving as a **controller**.
**viewMyData** and **dbconn** are methods in **dbConnection file**.
I have these 7 sql prepared statement in viewMyData method and I want to execute them and I want to get the data from database after successful execution of queries and the result is send to the servlet page and then from servlet the output will be show on a JSP page.How Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false)
```

deactivates autocommits, that enable you to send a batch of all these preparedstatements, then just create a method that executes all these queries to the database and in a finally block, set the autocommit to true.

Autocommit by default makes so that every transactions gets instantly saved in the database, with this behaviour, you can safely run all these queries as a one single atomic unit

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

1. Via setting database connection property to allow multiple queries (allowMultiQueries=true) separated by semi-colon by default.

Format your connection request, as below :

```
String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///test?allowMultiQueries=true";
```

2. Via stored procedure call which will returns cursors implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your queries like this:

```
"SELECT * From art_culture,education, ..., nature_wildlife where email = ?".
```

with this you will only get 1 resultset object.
Replace the ellipsis with a comma separated list of all your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Few problems I see in your question. Your code is far from what you are planning to do and there are lots of gaps to be filled (Even compile errors). When you seek help from the forum please put some effort on building your question.

Few suggestions

1. Creating a database connection each time you call the API is not a
   good practice. As this is an expensive operation. You cam use some connection pooling mechanism. There
   are libraries that do it for you. See this post for more info
   https://www.baeldung.com/java-connection-pooling.
2. Using combined data from 7 tables can also bring performance issues if these
   tables grow bigger.You must think of a better design if you need
   these to be fast in the long run. You can also add proper primary keys and indexes to these tables and optimize the sql query to make it fast.
3. Use some `.properties` file to store database credentials.

In here I have used `inner join` to join your 7 tables.

Please note that below code is not complete since I cannot write a complete code when your code is incomplete. I hope this will be enough for you to get an idea.

```
    public Connection dbconn() // modified to return connection
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        try
        {
            String JDBC_Driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
            Class.forName( JDBC_Driver );
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/connectiondb?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "" );
        }
        catch( Exception ex )
        {
            System.out.println( ex );
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public void viewMyData( String login_email_addr )
    {

        String sql = "SELECT * From art_culture ac\n" +
                "inner join education ed on ac.email =  ed.email\n" +
                "inner join fashion_beauty fb on fb.email = ac.email\n" +
                "inner join food_travel ft on ft.email = ac.email\n" +
                "inner join health_fitness hf on hf.email = ac.email\n" +
                "inner join literature lt on lt.email = ac.email\n" +
                "inner join nature_wildlife nw on nw.email = ac.email where ac.email = ? ;";
        try (Connection con = dbconn();
             PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement( sql )) // try with resources will close db resources automatically
        {
            ps.setString( 1, login_email_addr );

            try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery())
            {
                while(rs.next()){
                  // get your data here
                }

            }

        }
        catch( SQLException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

You must read the data and populate your data object and return it from this method.

Hope this helps.